# Problems with dualbooting ubuntu

Tags: uefi, windows-10

I have installed many ubuntu's before but with my laptop i'm out of reach.

I made a USB drive with ubuntu 16.10 using rufus and the UEFI option. I launched Ubuntu from the USB drive and opened gparted to make 2 partitions (1 swap 8GB and 1 200GB partition for ubuntu) alongside that i still have 3 partitions left 1Windows partition 1 recovery partition and 1 Startup partition (in efi format not sure what this is). I installed the grub on my 1TB drive. After installing everything completly i rebooted my laptop and it booted straight into windows 10. I have no way to acces the grub menu or ubuntu itself.

I have reinstalled ubuntu 6 times now all with different tutorials and diffrent ways.

Can someone assist me?

Thanks  Cyber.

Comment: Did you change the boot order on your BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: @DiogoVilela I have tried to change the boot order in the bios but i cannot see anything of ubuntu there and i also tried to change the UEFI settings but i couldn't find any boot order settings when pressign F8 to run the EUFI settings.

Comment: If you can, please take some pictures of the bios screen

Comment: These are pictures https://imgur.com/a/nft4u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out how to fix it.

My Efi files of my ubuntu and grub were not set as trusted in my bios.

What i did was ENABLED secure boot and went to my bios. In my bios it was called "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing". There i browsed to my efi file of my ubuntu and my grub allowing it to execute. After rebooting my laptop and going into my bios once again i had to change the boot order and there it was. I could finnaly see my grub and ubuntu in the boot order. After placing my grub at the top of the boot order i could finally boot in ubuntu.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is unusual. It sounds like your firmware might have this "trusted for executing" thing on top of the usual Secure Boot key checking -- or maybe your firmware lacks Microsoft's key for third-party executables. Either way, it's another wrinkle on the Secure Boot page.

Comment: ´@RodSmith Yeh i know thats why i was confused i turned off the secure boot nothing worked i turned it on and still nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: My suspicion is that you've installed the BIOS version of GRUB, which is next to useless on UEFI-based PCs that dual-boot with EFI-mode Windows installations.

Long answer: To begin with, you must understand the difference between two different types of firmware:

- **BIOS** -- The Basic Input/Output System (BIOS) was created for the first IBM PC back in the 1980s; then clones of it were reverse engineered by clone makers. (Thus, there are actually several independent implementations of "the" BIOS.) It's written in 16-bit assembly language and is very limited. To boot a BIOS-based PC, the BIOS reads the first sector of the hard disk and executes the code found there. This code is normally the first stage of a boot loader, which loads later stages of itself from elsewhere on the disk.
- **EFI** -- The Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI), or its version-2.x variant, the Unified EFI (UEFI) is a greatly expanded type of firmware that's written (mostly) in C and compiled for multiple architectures. On PCs, it's usually compiled into 64-bit code. An EFI-based computer boots by reading a boot loader stored as a file on a FAT partition known as the EFI System Partition (ESP). The pointer to the ESP is stored in NVRAM.

Based on your screen shot, your computer is clearly UEFI-based. Your first (text-mode) firmware screen shot shows that the NVRAM entries include a pointer to the Windows boot manager, but there's no evidence of a pointer to an Ubuntu boot manager. (It normally shows up as an entry called `ubuntu`.) Thus, I believe you have an EFI, an EFI-mode Windows install, and a BIOS-mode Ubuntu installation.

It's possible to boot a BIOS-mode boot loader from many UEFIs by using a feature called the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which is essentially a BIOS emulation layer. Doing it this way, with Windows installing and booting in EFI mode, is awkward, though.

Thus, the solution is likely to be to install an EFI-mode boot loader for Linux. There are several ways to do this, the easiest of which are:

- **Re-install Ubuntu** -- Re-run the Ubuntu installer, but be sure to boot the installation medium in EFI mode, not in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This should cause the EFI-mode version of GRUB 2 to be installed and everything should work.
- **Run Boot Repair in EFI mode** -- Boot the Ubuntu installer *in EFI mode* and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. This should install the EFI version of GRUB 2 on the disk, rescuing your current Ubuntu installation.
- **Install rEFInd** -- You can boot the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) which should enable you to boot your already-installed Ubuntu. Once you've done that, you can install rEFInd from its Debian package or PPA. rEFInd will then be your boot manager, not GRUB 2.

Note that the first two of those options ***require*** that you master your boot mode and have a USB flash drive that's been properly prepared. (Some tools omit the EFI boot loader when writing a USB flash drive from a `.iso` image file.) See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on the CSM, how to control it, and how to prepare boot media that can boot in EFI mode. rEFInd is an EFI-only tool, so it's harder to go wrong when preparing its USB drive -- at worst, it won't boot at all, rather than booting incorrectly in BIOS mode, as the Ubuntu installer might do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i will try to use the rEFInd first because i have no idea yet how to boot in EFI mode. I will let you know if i know more.

Comment: EDIT: I installed rEFInd but without succes after rebooting it goes in windows again.

Comment: I used efibootmgr to check and it sais rEFInd is my first boot order.